# Duplicate Footer Button appearing in My Inbox Fiori App

Tags: sapui5, workflow, sap-fiori

In My Inbox App,for Notification Work Items, Duplicate "Additional Information Required" footer button is displayed.

[image: Footer Button]

Workflow WS90000005 trigger's this work item and this button is maintained in 
it's task.

[image: Workflow]

No able to figure out why it is appearing twice.

Regards,
Sayed

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because there are two places where the user can define custom decision buttons. One of them is in the Business Workflow task (as in your screenshot). The other place is the SPRO transaction on the backend system (Gateway Service Enablement  Content  Workflow Settings  Maintain Task Names and Decision Options)
Please check whether you configured the buttons for the same task in both locations – possibly this is why the buttons appear twice.